# C# Substring OutOfRangeException With Correct String Length

Tags: c#, exception, substring, indexoutofrangeexception

I encountered out of range exception during a substring operation.

My string's length is 100, and the position of substrings are 58 and 94, which should not have given an out of range exception.

Below are the logs and code:

[image]

```
string parameters = item.GetFormattedValue("Parameters").ToString();
Console.WriteLine("parameters = " + parameters.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("parameters length: " + parameters.Length);

Console.ReadKey();

int p1 = parameters.IndexOf(@">");
Console.WriteLine("p1 = " + p1);

int p2 = parameters.IndexOf(@"<", parameters.IndexOf(@"<") + 1);
Console.WriteLine("p2 = " + p2);

Console.ReadKey();

string parametersSub = parameters.Substring(p1, p2);
Console.WriteLine("parametersSub: " + parametersSub);

Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [second argument in `Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.8#System_String_Substring_System_Int32_System_Int32_) is the length of the string to select, rather than the index to select up to.

Since your arguments are 58 and 94, you are trying to select from index 58 *for 94 characters* which goes outside the length of your string.

To select between the two indices, get the difference between the two and use that for the length to select:

```
int p1 = parameters.IndexOf(@">");
Console.WriteLine("p1 = " + p1);

int p2 = parameters.IndexOf(@"<", parameters.IndexOf(@"<") + 1);
Console.WriteLine("p2 = " + p2);

Console.ReadKey();

string parametersSub = parameters.Substring(p1, p2 - p1);
Console.WriteLine("parametersSub: " + parametersSub);
```

Of course, you should still check that both the start index, and length are within the bounds of the string.